# Delete multiple items in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

How to select and delete multiple items in a Custom ListView as in image? I have tried contextual action bar but it did not work. Any help would be appreciated. Any tutorial for this?

[image]

This is what I have tried:

[image]

Comment: why you use listview and not recycleview? recycleview do the same as listview and is more flexible. change to recycleview and try read this website explanation [link](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/statelistdrawables-for-recyclerview-selection/)

Comment: I have changed to recyclerview but cant seem to follow this link because it is not step by step

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use recylerview.Then whenever items are clicked, store their positions and when you press delete button, delete them from the list which is bound to recyclerview and use notifyItemRemoved flag to update your recyclerview.

Comment: how to select multiple items?

Comment: here you have to depend on bindviewholder method. define one list which will store the postion of selection item. as soon as item is clicked, it will go inside the list and call notifydatachanged method.. this notifydatamethod will call bindviewholder method again, and from here you can check that and ypu can show colored layout for the selected postion